# How can toggle scaleX to flip an image without animatoin

Tags: css, css-transforms

I want to flip an image instantly every 1000ms. I'm trying but the animation does what it's supposed to do (gradually flip the picture). If i can flip instantly the picture it will give the idea of a walking duck. I know I can use setInterval() but I'd rather do this in CSS only.

```
.duck {
    position: absolute;

    animation: flip-me;
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes flip-me {
    0% { transform: scaleX(1) }
    100% { transform: scaleX(-1) }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider [`steps()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function#The_steps()_class_of_timing_functions)

```css
img {
  animation: flip-me 2s steps(1) infinite;
}

@keyframes flip-me {
  50% { /*Pay attention: it's 50% not 100% !!*/
    transform: scaleX(-1)
  }
}

/*no need 0% or 100% state as they be set by default to scaleX(1)*/
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1069">
```